# What happens to the energy that electromagnetic waves carry, at infinity?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, magnetic-fields, electric-fields, energy-conservation

When a charge is there in free space, electric field is there surrounding it. But at infinite distance from the charge, electric field disappears as potential at infinity due to the charge is zero. So, I state field disappears.  Electromagnetic waves are just disturbance in electric and magnetic field, and it propagates. Also, we know it carries energy. But at infinity what happens to that energy as there is no field and disturbance too disappear?

Answer (score 3):

Your top-line question is about a wave.  Your body is more about statics.  I'm answering about a wave, hoping that was your real focus.

Infinity is not a place that the wave can reach.  It is the limit of going farther and farther away.  So in that sense the problem of the energy vanishing when it reaches infinity is not a real one.  At any finite distance from the source of your wave, the wave still exists and carries energy, but as you go ever farther away from the source the wave is more spread out over space and so the energy density keeps decreasing.  The limiting value of that process is 0 energy density, but, again, the wave never actually reaches infinity.

Viewed another way, if you want to hand-wave the issues about infinity being a concept rather than an actual location, it is really the energy density that is going to zero.  But at the same time the surface area of the wave front is going to infinity, so you have, in a loose sense, energy given by a density going to 0 times an area going to infinity.

Answer (score 2):

> What happens to the energy that electromagnetic waves carry, at infinity?

For spherical waves, $$A(x,t)=\mathcal{A}_0\frac{e^{i(kr-\omega t)}}{r}$$

The energy density stored in a wave is proportional to the square of its amplitude so the energy density goes like $1/r^2$. The Area of that wavefront increases as $r^2$. Thus the energy in the wavefront remains constant. Its energy density that decreases.

Answer (score 2):

Good question. The field amplitude tends to zero but the total energy does not. Why not? Because the volume containing the low-amplitude field tends to infinity. Overall the total energy stays fixed as a spherical wave propagates outwards.

Others already said this. What I want to do in this answer is add the following thought.

It might seem that this is an abstract idea only concerned with mathematical abstractions such as infinity, but it is not so. This kind of issue also comes in to many realistic and finite scenarios. For example, I had a case where the image of fluorescence from a trapped ion seemed to have too little total power. It was not as bright as expected on the basis of a separate measurement of the total power in the light field. It turned out in that example that there was a wide area of dim light around the central bright part. The point here is that although the wings of the intensity profile were dim, they nevertheless contained most of the energy because they were spread over a large area. It is easy to overlook possibilities like that.

Comment: I like how "the image of fluorescence from a trapped ion" is given as a "realistic" scenario here. Only on a physics forum! :)

Answer (score 0):

Since folks have given answers for the case of waves, I'll cover the field energy stored in a stationary point charge at infinity, for completeness. The electric field goes as $E\sim1/r^2$. Field energy density goes as $\frac{1}{2}\epsilon_0E^2\sim1/r^4$. Now, consider a spherical shell of radius $r$ and thickness $\mathrm{d}r$. The field energy contained in that shell thus goes as $\frac{1}{r^4}\cdot4\pi r^2\mathrm{d}r\sim\mathrm{d}r/r^2$. So, we see that the field energy of a stationary charge in free space goes to zero as we approach infinity.

Answer (score 0):

Electromagnetic waves are billions of photons spherically radiating outward from a source. The farther away they travel the more spread out they are. The inverse square law calculates that as:
Intensity=n divided by distance squared.

Answer (score -1):

As "infinity" is not a location, I'm going to assume you mean "as the radius from the source becomes arbitrarily large".

Classically, much like the electric field, the energy density would tend to zero. The important thing to note in the classical perspective is that the total energy does not change. While the energy density tends to zero, the space over which to integrate tends to infinite, which has a net cancelling effect.

Remembering that the energy of EM waves is quantized and that photons are a thing, we then realize that the EM waves cannot spread out perfectly uniformly ad infinitum. At some arbitrary radius, we should note that there are zero photons in some areas and a few in other areas (a measurement which would border on the impossible, but let's not quibble).

Then we remember that we live in the universe (I always forget that) and that this universe is expanding. Given that the energy density of radiation is related to expansion as $~\frac{1}{a^4}$, where $a$ is effectively the amount of expansion, that means that the total energy carried by this electromagnetic wave actually decreases as it travels through this expanding universe (a requirement for reaching "infinity"). By the time it reaches "infinity", **there will be no energy left in the wave** to speak of, regardless what other paradigms, effects, or mechanics you want to consider (barring alternate universes).